# Add and remove child

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm in need for some help regarding the creation and suppression of child nodes:

I have to update a XML file containing `OUT` conditions `(OUTCOND)` with `SIGN="+/-"` and, as a new normalization standards, I have to put the ones with `SIGN="+"` after the ones with `SIGN="-"`.

I was suggested to create new ones with the same attributes (I just need `'NAME'` actually) as the former ones and then suppress them. So here is my (shortened) PowerShell code:

```bsh
@(Select-Xml -Xml $dataXML -XPath "//OUTCOND[@SIGN=""+""]" | foreach {
    $_.Node
}) | foreach {
    $OUTNAMENODE = $_.NAME
    $OUTCONDNEW = $dataXML.CreateElement("OUTCOND") 
    $OUTCONDNEW.SetAttribute("NAME", "$OUTNAMENODE")
    $OUTCONDNEW.SetAttribute("ODATE", "ODAT")
    $OUTCONDNEW.SetAttribute("SIGN", "+")
    $_.ParentNode.AppendChild($OUTCONDNEW) | Out-Null

    $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) | Out-Null
}
```

but `$OUTNAMENODE` returns me only one name (there should be ~ 20) and I can't understand why for now (I'm aware the `RemoveChild($_)` has to be modified BTW).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked for me when I tested it with sample XML data I cooked up. I would, however, suggest some simplifications, since you already seem to have an XML object. The following should simply move the existing nodes to the end of their parent without the need to re-create them:

```
@($dataXML.SelectNodes("//OUTCOND[@SIGN='+']")) | ForEach-Object {
    $parent = $_.ParentNode
    $cutout = $parent.RemoveChild($_)
    $parent.AppendChild($cutout) | Out-Null
}
```

If you're still experiencing problems please update your question with sample input as well as the desired and actual output from that sample input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the simplification you proposed worked perfectly and is far easier indeed.